# Hidden top TD border in Internet Explorer 8

Tags: html, css, html-table, internet-explorer-8, border

I have been trying to solve this style problem for the whole day, but in vain.

http://jsfiddle.net/9HP9Q/1/

The table lines must have gray borders around them. It works fine on all browsers except Internet Explorer 8.

```
.order_table table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
.order_table table tbody tr {
   border: 1px solid #DEDEDE;
}
```

It does indeed give border to the whole table, except the first `<TD>` but then I tried forcing it using

```
.order_table table td.product_format {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #DEDEDE;
  border-top: 1px solid #DEDEDE;
}
```

But it did not work. Can anybody guide me to the right way?

Comment: seems like the `tr` is not taking 100% width of the table in IE

Comment: @simo L check my answer answer and let me know if any changes required.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### The problem:

```
.order_table table tbody tr {
   border: 1px solid #DEDEDE;
   //IE put the background color upside the border
   background-color: #FAFAFA;
}
```

#### The solution:

```
.order_table table tbody tr {
   border: 1px solid #DEDEDE;
   //Deleted the background-color
}
```

#### Working example:

http://jsfiddle.net/9HP9Q/2/

Comment: Thanks. I moved the `background-color` to `table` (and gave the header a white background) in order to keep the old style.

Answer (score 2):

i think you want the output like that in fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/9HP9Q/3/

i have just change the color to red for easy visibility so you please chaged it as per your need.

```
.product_name {
font-size: 30px;
font-family: 'MisoBold';
text-transform: uppercase;
color: #3F3F3F;
}
.order_table table {
margin-left: 0px;
width: 390px;
xheight: 100px;
border-collapse: collapse;
}
thead {
border-bottom: 1px solid #D5D3D0;
margin-bottom: 5px;
}

.order_table table {
border-collapse: collapse;
}
.order_table table tbody tr {
/*border: 1px solid #DEDEDE;*/
    border: 1px solid red;
/*background-color: #FAFAFA;*/
}
.order_table table td.product_format {
border-collapse: collapse;
padding-left: 20px;
font-weight: bold;
/*border-bottom: 1px solid #DEDEDE;
border-top: 1px solid #DEDEDE;*/
border-color: #DEDEDE;
position: relative;
height: 1px;
}
.price-promo {
top: 0 !important;
}
.qty_selector {
padding: 0px;
background: none;
border-top: none;
float: left;
  clear: both;
}
input[type="text"] {
width: 58px;
border: 1px solid #DEDEDE;
color: #333;
height: 23px;
padding-left: 8px;
overflow: hidden;
}
.qty_selector .qty_btn {
width: 11px;
margin-top: -2px;
padding-left: 3px;
background: none;
height: 32px;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
.qty_selector .qty_btn a {
width: 11px;
padding: 0px;
background: none;
float: left;
margin: 1px 5px 1px 0;
}
.order_table table td {
vertical-align: middle;
padding: 7px;
}
.order_table table td.unit_price {
padding-right: 0;
text-align: center;
}
.unit_price .pricebykg {
font-size: 10px;
font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
margin-top: 10px;
}
```

and i have commented the code which is not necessary.

please let me know if i am lagging some where to understand your question.